# Is there a certificate definition for polyL?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, space-bounded

Arora explained in his [book](http://theory.cs.princeton.edu/complexity/) a certificate definition for $\mathsf{NL}$ using a read-once tape. Can we apply a similar definition for the class [$\mathsf{polyL}$](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:P#polyl)?

Comment: The question would be more useful if you provided a definition of the class $\mathsf{polyL}$.